# Does page fault necessarily cause context switch in Linux?

Tags: linux, multithreading, linux-kernel

While I understand that some context switches are caused by page faults, does a page fault definitely cause context switch?

Comment: I think yes. Time to read page from disk is too long to let processor waste it.

Comment: Memory-management protection level context switch, yes.  Thread context switch, not if there is nothing else to run.  If there are no ready threads to switch to, a context-switch cannot happen.

Comment: Suppose that we always have ready threads.

Comment: @MartinJames There is always another thread to switch to: the idle thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If this happens because your program in user-mode leads to a "page_fault" the CPU in which it is running receives the interrupt of "page_fault" and the context of the current execution must be saved in the system's stack space (typically is the firmware to do this) so that the control is passed to the handler of "page_fault" ("ENTRY(page_fault)" defined in /kernel/entry.S).

Answer (score 0):

The page fault can be occured in user mode or kernel mode. If it's occured in user mode, regardless of the result, resulting in a context switch. And occured in kernel mode, in addition to context switch, as accessing address 0 can lead to kernel panic.